# Configuring Homestead error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

When I use `vagrant up` command I have this error message:

```
Bringing machine 'name' up with 'parallels' provider...
==> name: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> name: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> name: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
name: Adapter 0: shared
name: Adapter 1: hostonly
==> name: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> name: Forwarding ports...
name: 80 => 8000
name: 443 => 44300
name: 3306 => 33060
name: 5432 => 54320
name: 8025 => 8025
name: 27017 => 27017
==> name: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> name: Booting VM...
==> name: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

On Parallels the VM is created and when I launch I arrive to login page.

I'm using PhpStorm on Mac and followed this tutorial: http://www.pascallandau.com/blog/laravel-with-phpunit-on-vagrant-in-phpstorm/

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: enable GUI mode and follow the progress. As you say the VM is up and running and you can login, it might be you need to increate the timeout, so something else is blocking ssh. if you login, do you see the `/home/vagrant/.ssh` folder with correct permission and authorized key

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I enable GUI for parallels?

Comment: hum ok you cant enable for vagrant, but you have access to parallel to monitor the progress no ?

Comment: I increase the timeout, but the issue remain. On every boot I have this message "a start job is running for raise network interfaces" after this I arrive to login. But it still said the same error for vagrant.

Comment: whats your vagrant config ? did you try to use a bridge network ?

Comment: The vagrantfile is the default one. Internet doesn't work in this VM. It set by default with bridge network, I test other but doesn't work. On my Windows VM I put wireless and it work fine.

Comment: @suifer If you run all those commands (e.g. `vagrant up`) outside of IDE (when PhpStorm is closed etc) -- does it behave the same? Because so far I do not see anything related to PhpStorm...